# Fetching Room relational database values with LiveData Transformations

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

New to Android and Java and is trying to learn by making an app. But now I'm stuck at fetching the relational data correctly and displaying it within RecyclerView (using `ListAdapter` and Infinite Scroll).

Here is a gist of what I have been doing so far.

The Entities:
Items:

```
@Entity(...)
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long item_id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title = "";

    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("labels")
    @Expose
    private List<String> tags;

    ...
    }
```

Tags:

```
@Entity(...)
public class Tag {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tag_name")
    private String tagName;
    ...
}
```

Relation:

```
@Entity(...)
public class ItemTags {

    private long item_id;

    private long tag_id;
    ...
}
```

Retrofit:

```
public class ApiClient {
    // Init in Constructor
    private final MutableLiveData<List<Item>> mObservableData;
    ...

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getObservableData() {
        return mObservableData;
    }

    public void onResponse(...) {
        ...
        mObservableData.postValue(responseBody.getItems());

    }
}
```

Repository: Inserting into the database.

```
public void getNetworkCallback() {
    if (isFirstCallbackNeeded()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getNetworkCallback: Called");
        mClient.getFirstCallback();
        insertItemsToDb();
    }
}

private void insertItemsToDb() {
    LiveData<List<Item>> downloadedData = mClient.getObservableData();
        if (items != null) {
            mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
                List<Long> itemIds = insertAllItems(items);

                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    long itemId = itemIds.get(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "insertItemsToDb: " + itemId);

                    if (itemId != -1) {
                        List<String> labelNames = items.get(i).getTags();
                        for (String labelName : labelNames) {
                            insertUniqueTagName(new Tag(labelName));

                            long tagId = fetchIdByTagName(labelName);
                            insertRelational_ItemTags(new ItemTags(itemId, tagId));
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is well up to this. When the database is empty and after getting the response, the data is successfully inserted into the database.

But whenever I try to fetch the tags related to each item, to be shown within the RecyclerView, the same time, using `Transformations.map`, the `Tags` List returned is `null` or empty.

```
public LiveData<List<Item>> fetchAllItems() {
    LiveData<List<Item>> itemLiveData = mItemDao.fetchAllItems();
    itemLiveData = Transformations.map(itemLiveData, input -> {
        for (Item item : input) {
            mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
                long itemId = item.getItem_id();
                Log.d(TAG, "getTransformedObservableItems: itemId: " + itemId);
                List<String> tagNames = fetchRelationalTagNameById(itemId);
                Log.d(TAG, "getTransformedObservableItems: tagNames: " + tagNames);
                item.setTags(tagNames);
            });
        }
        return input;
    });

    return itemLiveData;
}
```

Log:

```
getTransformedObservableItems: itemId: 1
getTransformedObservableItems: tagNames: []
getTransformedObservableItems: itemId: 2
getTransformedObservableItems: tagNames: []
...
```

Worth mentioning that I am observing only the List of Items in Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item")
LiveData<List<Item>> fetchAllItems();
```

ViewModel:

```
public ItemViewModel(ApiRepository apiRepository) {
    mObservableLiveData = apiRepository.fetchAllItems();
}

public LiveData<List<Item>> getObservableLiveData() {
    return mObservableLiveData;
}
```

Activity:

```
repository.getNetworkCallback();
// RecyclerView ListAdapter
mViewModel.getObservableLiveData().observe(this, adapter::submitList);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the logic correct? Any suggestion is helpful.

Thank you.

---

**Update:**

After several tries I have found out that using `removeObserver()` on `LiveData<List<Item>> fetchAllItems()` within the `insertItemsToDb()` `onChanged()` method, I'm able to achieve the result.

But as I'm using `Executors`, sadly, `removeObserver()` is not allowed on background threads.

Anyone with any suggestions?

---

**Solution** `Transformations#switchMap` as suggested by @Pycpik

```
public LiveData<List<Item>> fetchAllTransformedItems() {
    LiveData<List<Item>> itemLiveData = fetchAllItems();
    itemLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(itemLiveData, input -> {
        final MutableLiveData<List<Item>> itemListMutableData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
            for (Item item : input) {
                long itemId = item.getItem_id();
                List<String> tagNames = fetchRelationalTagNameById(itemId);
                item.setTags(tagNames);
            }
            itemListMutableData.postValue(input);
        });
        return itemListMutableData;
    });

    return itemLiveData;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly in the same situation, but below is how I handle fetching data with relation using `switchMap` and RxJava. Maybe it can help you.

```
public LiveData<List<Item>> fetchAllItems() {
    LiveData<List<Item>> itemLiveData = mItemDao.fetchAllItems();
    itemLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(itemLiveData, input -> {
        MutableLiveData<List<Item>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Completable.fromAction(() -> {
            for (Item item : input) {
                long itemId = item.getItem_id();
                Log.d(TAG, "getTransformedObservableItems: itemId: " + itemId);
                List<String> tagNames = fetchRelationalTagNameById(itemId);
                Log.d(TAG, "getTransformedObservableItems: tagNames: " + tagNames);
                item.setTags(tagNames);
            }
        })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {mutableLiveData.postValue(input);});
        return mutableLiveData;
    });
    return itemLiveData;
}
```

Comment: And yes I was looking for examples on how `Transformations.switchMap` works and this is what I needed. Posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

meybe try foreGround thread 
or part of code use it this

```
activity.runOnUiThread(() ->{
});
```

Comment: But I'm not on an activity. `fetchAllItems` is in repository class.

Comment: pass this(context) to this class and cast it into Activity